# Fragment layout not showing after opening through bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using navigation component to work with lets say fragmentA, bottom sheet(dialog), fragmentB.

fragmentA has a button which opens bottom sheet, and bottom sheet also has a button which will open fragmentB.
Now as I am using navigation component, I used NavHostFragment to navigate through bottom sheet to fragmentB.

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(GuestBottomSheet.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_guestBottomSheet_to_foodSelection,bundle);
```

Now after clicking on button that opens fragmentB, bottom sheet is getting collapsed and I am still seeing fragmentA.
I using logs to check fragmentB and I found that fragmentB is opened but its layout is not showing at my screen. I tried changing background color still its not showing.

**Navigation_graph**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/guest_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/guestWelcome">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/guestWelcome"
        android:name="com.androboot.procook.GuestWelcome"
        android:label="fragment_guest_welcome"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_guest_welcome" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_guestWelcome_to_guestBottomSheet"
            app:destination="@id/guestBottomSheet" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/guestBottomSheet"
        android:name="com.androboot.procook.bottomSheet.GuestBottomSheet"
        tools:layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_guest">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_guestBottomSheet_to_foodSelection"
            app:destination="@id/foodSelection" />
    </dialog>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/foodSelection"
        android:name="com.androboot.procook.FoodSelection"
        android:label="fragment_food_selection"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_food_selection" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Did you try setting your Fragment B as start destination and checking if it will inflate its layout?

Comment: No, I will try that. But as I am using databinding and I saw all the views through it. So I assumed it's binded properly.

Comment: Can you show how you inflate layout with databinding?

Comment: View v= View.inflate(getContext(),R.layout.fragmentB, null);

Comment: Can you edit your original post with full code of 2 fragments? Fragment Guest Bottom Sheet, and Fragment Food Selection?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it. By changing to bi=DatabindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(),R.layout.fragmentB);

Comment: You should rather use .inflate instead of setContentView since its fragment

Comment: Can you write the code coz it's not working that way.

Comment: Post the code of your two fragment that I asked for above and I will take a look